# Breaking down bank statement by categories in R

Tags: r, aggregate

This is a sample part of a bank statement:

```
Category<-c(
"Merchandise",
"Dining",
"Lodging",
"Other Services",
"Dining",
"Merchandise",
"Merchandise",
"Other Services",
"Entertainment",
"Merchandise",
"Merchandise",
"Internet",
"Other Services",
"Merchandise",
"Merchandise",
"Merchandise",
"Other Services",
"Phone/Cable",
"Airfare",
"Airfare",
"Other Services",
"Merchandise",
"Merchandise",
"Internet",
"Other Services",
"Other Services",
"Phone/Cable",
"Other Services",
"Healthcare"
)

Debit<-as.numeric(c(
"26.34",
"4.75",
"9.88",
"31.26",
"8.67",
"64.64",
"5.18",
"15.5",
"10",
"12.93",
"10.02",
"6.95",
"39.93",
"16.39",
"24",
"40.35",
"27.33",
"11.12",
"214.2",
"214.2",
"4",
"86.28",
"19.99",
"19.99",
"13.68",
"205",
"10.96",
"85",
"1525"
))

df<-data.frame(Category,Debit)
```

with the following output:

```
         Category   Debit
1     Merchandise   26.34
2          Dining    4.75
3         Lodging    9.88
4  Other Services   31.26
5          Dining    8.67
6     Merchandise   64.64
7     Merchandise    5.18
8  Other Services   15.50
9   Entertainment   10.00
10    Merchandise   12.93
11    Merchandise   10.02
12       Internet    6.95
13 Other Services   39.93
14    Merchandise   16.39
15    Merchandise   24.00
16    Merchandise   40.35
17 Other Services   27.33
18    Phone/Cable   11.12
19        Airfare  214.20
20        Airfare  214.20
21 Other Services    4.00
22    Merchandise   86.28
23    Merchandise   19.99
24       Internet   19.99
25 Other Services   13.68
26 Other Services  205.00
27    Phone/Cable   10.96
28 Other Services   85.00
29     Healthcare 1525.00
```

From there, to see the total amount of money I have spent in individual categories, for example "Merchandise", I have to do this:

```
> sum(df$Debit[which(df$Category=="Merchandise")])
[1] 306.12
```

But it is cumbersome to do that for each category one by one. I was wondering if there is a neater way to display it so that in one column I get all the levels listed for `df$Category`, and in the second column the sum for each category.

Something like this:

```
Merchandise 306.12
Other Services  421.7
Phone/Cable 22.08
etc...
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps, the easiest way would be to use `dplyr`. I would think of something like `df %>% group_by(Category) %>% summarise(sum=sum(Debit))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R, you can use `aggregate()`:

```
aggregate(Debit ~ Category, df, FUN = sum)
```

This gives:

```
        Category   Debit
1        Airfare  428.40
2         Dining   13.42
3  Entertainment   10.00
4     Healthcare 1525.00
5       Internet   26.94
6        Lodging    9.88
7    Merchandise  306.12
8 Other Services  421.70
9    Phone/Cable   22.08
```

Comment: All the answers are great, but this would be the simplest. Thanks!

Comment: this was not exactly part of the question, but is there a way to present the results in a sorted way, `Debit` from highest to lowest?

Comment: If you saved the previous result as `sums` you could do `sums[order(-sums$Debit), ]`. Only on my phone right now but that should work.

Answer (score 2):

Also easily solved with the package `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt[, list(DebitTotal = sum(Debit)), by = Category]

#           Category DebitTotal
# 1:    Merchandise     306.12
# 2:         Dining      13.42
# 3:        Lodging       9.88
# 4: Other Services     421.70
# 5:  Entertainment      10.00
# 6:       Internet      26.94
# 7:    Phone/Cable      22.08
# 8:        Airfare     428.40
# 9:     Healthcare    1525.00
```

Answer (score 1):

You also have the classic SQL group by option to use.
You first need to load the sqldf package.
library(sqldf)

`` sqldf (" 
      select Category, sum(Debit) `debit_sum`
      from df
      group by Category
       ") ``

It will give you the following

`Category     sum
1        Airfare  428.40
2         Dining   13.42
3  Entertainment   10.00
4     Healthcare 1525.00
5       Internet   26.94
6        Lodging    9.88
7    Merchandise  306.12
8 Other Services  421.70
9    Phone/Cable   22.08`